# Resharper: Pull Members Up from base class?

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-7.1

Using Resharper 7.1, C#

I have a class `Apple` that is based on `Fruit`

```
public partial class Apple: Fruit, IEat
```

Using the command **Refactor/Pull Members Up**, how do I add the **Fruit.Eat()** method to the Interface?

The Resharper UI only lets me add `Apple` members.

Comment: Please add more details. Maybe you need Extract Interface refactoring? Or you need to invoke Refactoring from the Fruit class, not from Apple?

Comment: There's no interface here??

Answer (score 0):

The code above (where `Apple` inherits from both `Fruit` and `IEat`) is redundant. I think how you want it is that `Apple` inherits from `Fruit`

```
public class Apple : Fruit
```

and `Fruit` inherits from `IEat`

```
public class Fruit : IEat
```

If `Fruit` inherits from `IEat` as I have suggested here, then you should be able to do the Resharper "pull members up" from the Fruit class.

If `Fruit` doesn't inherit from `IEat`, you can't do the refactoring.